# How to return arrays.......?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
package round1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathewJhon {
    int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scn.nextInt();
        int y = scn.nextInt();
        int nth = scn.nextInt();
        int a[] = genrate(x, y);
        System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + nth);

    }

    private static int[] genrate(int x, int y) {
        for(int i=1;i<y;i++){
            int val=(i*(i+1))/2;
             int a[]= new int[y];
              a[i]=val;
        }           
        return a;

    }

}
```

Comment: For one, you need to declare `a[]` outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: You should read your error (and warning) messages

Comment: You can only use a variable which is in scope, it doesn't matter if it's an array or not.

Comment: Not to mention you were making a new array every iteration which could be costly to your memory at some point.

Comment: In the future, when posting questions, if there's an error message you don't understand, please include it with your question so that we can explain what it means and how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare your array at the method scope:

```
private static int[] genrate(int x, int y) {
    int a[] = new int[y];
    for(int i=1; i<y; i++){
        int val = (i*(i+1))/2;
        a[i] = val;
    }           
    return a;
}
```

When you declare a variable inside a loop, it only exists inside that loop.

Note that your original method was creating a new array each time through the loop, so you were not filling a single array with values (like you apparently intended). Also, the parameter `x` doesn't seem to be used; is that perhaps another error?

Comment: +1 you're quick! Mid-typing your answered appeared

Answer (score 2):

Your array's scope is limited to the `for` loop in this case. Try this:

```
private static int[] genrate(int x, int y) {
int a[] = new int[y];
for(int i=1;i<y;i++){
    int val=(i*(i+1))/2;
      a[i]=val;
}           
return a;
```

}

When you declare any kind of variable inside of a loop or method in Java, it's can't be accessed outside of that loop or method.